# Fetching specific number of records not working in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table which contains 1000 records.

I needed to pull 100 records at a time so I used `setFetchSize` in the hibernate Criteria as below(`Deal` is the entity object)

```
 List<Deal> dealList= sess.createCriteria(Deal.class).setFetchSize(100).list();
```

But, after the above query when I printed the `dealList` size as

```
System.out.println("no. of deals "+dealList.size());
```

it gave 1000 records not 100 records.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need [setMaxResults()](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setMaxResults%28int%29).

*Fetch size* is a JDBC optimisation and not a restriction on the query performed. See [this thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?54787-HibernateTemplate-s-setFetchSize%28%29-and-setMaxResults%28%29) for more info on `setFetchSize()` and `setMaxSize()`, and [this thread](http://benjisimon.blogspot.com/2007/07/hibernate-performance-tip-setfetchsize.html) for how the two can work together for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setMaxResults` with `setFirstResult` to get next records.

**Update**

From `java.sql.Statement#setFetchSize` javadoc:

> Gives the JDBC driver a hint as to the number of rows that should 
>         be fetched from the database when more rows are needed for
>         `ResultSet` objects genrated by this `Statement`. 
>         If the value specified is zero, then the hint is ignored.
>         The default value is zero.

Comment: what's the use of setFetchSize then? May be my understanding is wrong in case of setFetchSize? can you please tell me?

Answer (score 0):

use `setMaxResults(100)` to restrict number of rows fetched to 100